# How get object of dropped item in drag-and-drop example?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

With AlpineJs 2.8 I  remake drag-and-drop example from
https://codepen.io/trovster/pen/oNjGGMq

based on dynamic data and when item dropped I need to get item ID of any element,
I try to make it parsing event on drop event. Looking into
console  https://prnt.sc/115ikf5 I see event.srcElement, but it is strin, not object,
from which I want to get ID:

```
        toListingDropped: function (event) {
            console.log('toListingDropped event::')
            console.log(event)

            console.log('toListingDropped event.srcElement::')
            console.log(event.srcElement) // I expect this link to dragable item - but I see html code, not object
            console.log('toListingDropped event.srcElement.id::')
            console.log(event.srcElement.id) // I need to get thuis ID
```

Pen link : https://codepen.io/sergeynilov/pen/zYNobRP

How to get object of dropped item ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a decision with setting user info in Transfer Object:

```
x-on:dragstart.self="
    dragging = true;
    event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed='move';
    event.dataTransfer.setData('user', JSON.stringify(nextUser));
"
```

and reading these data on drop event :

```
let droppedUser = JSON.parse(event.dataTransfer.getData('user'))
```